# face recognition on tensorflow convolution neural network only gets the accuracy 0.05

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

os:win10

face database:yale face database(15 different people, totally about 160 images)

programming language : python on tensorflow

I use the tensorflow to do face recognition by CNN, but the accuracy is only about 0.05. (In convolution layer ,there was no padding)
The network structure is :
Conv1-->max pooling-->Conv2-->max pooling-->full connect(15 output)

the code as followings:
some definition just like tensorflow examples:

```
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID") # no padding

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                         strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID")  # no padding
```

The first Conv layer:

```
# first layer
SHAPE = [None, 64, 64, 1]
Y_SHAPE = [None, 15]
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=SHAPE, name="x_data")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=Y_SHAPE, name="y_true")

W1_shape = [7, 7, 1, 6]
b1_shape = [6]
with tf.name_scope("Conv1"):
    W_conv1 = weight_variable(W1_shape)
    b_conv1 = bias_variable(b1_shape)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights", W_conv1)
#     tf.summary.histogram("bias", b_conv1)

    a_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
    a_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(a_conv1)

    # a_pool1 shape : (29， 29， 6)



# second layer
W2_shape = [8, 8, 6, 16]
b2_shape = [16]
with tf.name_scope("Conv2"):
    W_conv2 = weight_variable(W2_shape)
    b_conv2 = bias_variable(b2_shape)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights", W_conv2)
#     tf.summary.histogram("bias", b_conv2)

    a_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(a_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
    a_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(a_conv2)

    # a_pool2 shape (11， 11， 16)



# full connect
W_out_shape = [11*11*16, 15]
b_out_shape = [15]

with tf.name_scope("sigmoid"):
    W_out= weight_variable(W_out_shape)
    b_out = bias_variable(b_out_shape)

    a_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(a_pool2, [-1, 11*11*16])
    z_out = tf.matmul(a_pool2_flat, W_out) + b_out

    a_out = tf.nn.sigmoid(z_out)



# train and evaluate
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=a_out)

batch_size = 40
train_index = np.arange(90)

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(a_out, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(1000):    # epochs=1000
        # index shuffle
        np.random.shuffle(train_index)
        batch_train = train_data[train_index[:batch_size]] 
        batch_labels = train_labels[train_index[:batch_size]]

        if i % 10 == 0:   # print accuracy each ten epoches
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch_train, y:batch_labels})
            print("step %d, train accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))

        _, loss_ = sess.run([train_step, loss], feed_dict={x:batch_train, y:batch_labels})

    test_index = np.arange(74)
    np.random.shuffle(test_index)
    print("test accuracy:", sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x:test_data[test_index], y:test_labels[test_index]}))

writer.close()
```

The following pictures are my output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm by no means an expert on the topic of machine learning but from a quick look at your code:

1. Convolutional Layers don't aren't part of the actual classification task. They extract features from unaugmented input data. 
2. Neither do Maxpooling Layers.
3. The only layer that is actually able to learn the classfication is your 15 Unit Fully Connected layer.

I would try to to at least a stack of fully connected layers and probably one or two with more than just 15 neurons.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is incorrect network structure

```
a_out = tf.nn.sigmoid(z_out)
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=a_out)
```

should be

```
a_out = z_out
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=a_out)
```

softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits applies softmax internally, so applying sigmoid beforehand makes no sense (and makes training much harder if not impossible). In your current setting, the probability of a single class lies in [0, 0.345] instead of [0, 1], as with fully saturated sigmoids the softmax is:

```
exp(1) / (14*exp(-1) + exp(1)) ~= 0.345
```

Two other problems are:

- learning rate used seems completely arbitrary, you might want to switch yo Adam which is less sensitive to invalid learning rates
- initialisation scheme seems arbitrary too, you might want to reduce the std.
- instead of printing accuracy - print the loss. If it is not going down on the training set then you have errors in the training. If it is, but too slowly - adjust the learning rate and so on.